# Convert an ISO date to seconds since epoch in linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, date, timezone, epoch

I have a date in the ISO format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:SS (e.g. 2014-02-14T12:30). I'd like to convert it in seconds since epoch using only the date command in linux bash.

All the dates refer to UTC locale.

I know that this question is easily eligible for duplicate... there are billions of questions about converting dates from one format to another but I can't find my particular scenario

thank you...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With GNU date (from the [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) package), specify the date to parse with `-d` and seconds since epoch with `%s`

```
$ date -d"2014-02-14T12:30" +%s
1392381000
```

---

Note that this will interpret the date to be parsed as being in your **local time zone**. If you want `date` to use a specific time zone, you must specify that, either via the variable TZ (which changes the default time zone for `date`), or in the date string. For UTC:

```
$ TZ=UTC date -d"2014-02-14T12:30" +%s
1392381000
```

or in the string, according to ISO 8601:

```
$ date -d"2014-02-14T12:30Z" +%s
1392381000
```

See [ISO 8601 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for how to specify other time zones in the date string.

Comment: that's exactly what I tried... but it seems to report a wrong number if compared to the one given at http://www.epochconverter.com/. Can you explain to me what's going on?

Comment: I mean, "date" output seems to be several hours late from the value given at www.epochconverter.com

Comment: I tried the "-u" option but it seems not to work. "-u" means set/print UTC coordinates

Comment: either as BMW suggests or include the timezone in the input to date, so $ date -d"2014-02-14T12:30 EDT" +%s

Comment: EDT option doesn't work. I have date from coreutils 8.4 (Centos 6.0)

Comment: An alternative that might work: $ TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date -d"2014-02-14T12:30" +%s

Comment: Replace 'T' with whitespace.

Comment: This answer did not address timezones. I edited to add this - hope that's ok.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier if you install `gdate` to deal with date strings that have timezones with nano second precision

`install coreutils` and you will get `gdate` along

on mac `brew install coreutils`

```
gdate --date="2010-10-02T09:35:58.203Z" +%s%N
```

This is particularly useful when inserting the time series value into influxdb

in a shell script `variable = $(gdate --date="2010-10-02T09:35:58.203Z" +%s%N)`

```
echo $variable
```

Comment: Your answer seems to refer to a specific UNIX variant (MacOS X presumably). Please clarify what variant you are talking about - otherwise this answer is only confusing. For example, on Linux there is no "install" command, and on Debian there is a "coreutils" package, but it does not contain "gdate" (only "date").

Comment: HI @sleske sorry i have moved away from the project and don't have the environmental information you have asked for